# Why PendingIntent cannot be put into Bundle?

Tags: android

I'm creating `Intent`, and put a `PendingIntent` into it's extras.

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(...);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("foo", pending);
```

Looks fine, because `PendingIntent` implements `Parcellable`. No documentation says I cannot do that.

But when I try to get it in my service, I get:

```
Parcel android.os.Parcel@ab33c24: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6619252 at offset 208
```

Is it fixable, or I should avoid putting PendingIntent into Bundle?

Android version: 6.0.1.

UPDATE:
I need it to cancel previously created PendingIntent-s:

```
locationManager.cancel(updateListenerPendingIntent);
alarmManager.cancel(someAlarmPendingIntent);
```

Comment: You don't need the original, you can recreate it with the same ID in order to cancel it, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681095/cancel-an-alarmmanager-pendingintent-in-another-pendingintent

Comment: If the alternate solution in the other comment doesn't work for you, post the code that gets the PendingIntent from the intent in the service.  I cannot reproduce the error running similar code on the 6.0 emulator.